# How to upload image with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs and i am using nextjs framework, I am trying to upload image with Axios (post method api) and i will use "api in php", How can i do this ? I tried with following code but its giving me following error
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'
I tried with following code but giving me errors ( mentioned below code )

**HTML**

```
<input type="file"  
       className="file-upload-default"  
       onChange={handleFileSelect}/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("selectedFile", selectedFile);

try {
     const response = await axios({
                                   method: "post",
                                   url: "/api/upload/file",
                                   data: formData,
                                   headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
                                   });
    } 
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error) 
        // getting error 
        // "Argument of type 'string | null' 
        // is not assignable to parameter 
        // of type 'string | Blob'"
    }  

    const handleFileSelect = (event : any) => {
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0])
        // getting error "Cannot find name 'setSelectedFile'"
    }
```

Comment: where did you define selectedFile state ?

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I searched on google and use that code, kindly update code and explain how can i do this ?

Comment: post the complete code in this file

Comment: @sarasara I posted an answer, please let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 0):

First error that you faced in catch is because that you didn't assing type for selectedFile state so you need to add type `string | Blob` for it

and for second one I'm not sure where you define selectedFile  state but it seems that handleFileSelect function is not in the file where selectedFile is defined

here is what I did, I hope it helps:

```
 const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<string | Blob>('');
  const handleFileUpload = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('selectedFile', selectedFile);
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/upload/file',
        data: formData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleFileSelect = (event: any) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileSelect} />
      <button onClick={handleFileUpload}>Upload!</button>
    </>)
```